# Envio de arquivo por CURL php

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou com um problema estou usando um PHP inferior ao 5.5, ou seja não tenho a função `curl_file_create` para eu usar, mesmo assim não estou conseguindo enviar poderia me ajudar ?

```
public function enviaArquivo($arquivo){

    $ch = curl_init('https://site.com.br/upload_direto?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [    
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [          
          'File' => "@/var/www/site.com.br/sistema/php/cron/".$arquivo,
          'Token'=> 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ]
    ]);

    $resposta = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $resposta;
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos comentários do manual do PHP, pode criar a própria função `curl_file_create`:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
    function curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '', $postname = '') {
        return "@$filename;filename="
            . ($postname ?: basename($filename))
            . ($mimetype ? ";type=$mimetype" : '');
    }
}
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php#114539

Comment: Obrigado, consegui !